# Retrieve ID number from MYSQL using AJAX & PHP then hashchange URL using retrieved ID

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to retrieve the latest video ID number from my database and then use that ID number to hashchange my URL and display the corresponding video. My PHP is working and returning a result but I'm not sure how to take that result and use it in jQuery so that I can use it for the hashchange. I haven't used jQuery much before so any detailed help would be amazing! Please find my current code below. The main question I have is how do I pass the `$vidarray` to jQuery so I can use that variable?

**videoprocess.php**

```
<?php
    // Connect To DB
    $hostname="localhost";
    $database="MYDB";
    $username="root";
    $password="";

    @$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
        or die("Could not connect to server " . mysql_error()); 
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $database) or die("Error: Could not connect to the database: " . mysql_error());

    /*Check for Connection*/
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        // Display Error message if fails
        echo 'Error, could not connect to the database please try again again.';
        exit();
    }

    $query = "SELECT VIDEOID FROM JubileeTouchVideo ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($conn));


    //create an array
    $vidarray = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $vidarray = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($vidarray);

    //close the db connection
    mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

**videoprocess jquery**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "data.json",
    //force to handle it as text
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
        //data downloaded so we call parseJSON function
        //and pass downloaded data
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        //Not sure what to do after this
    }
});
```

Comment: I would say you need to call your `function hashchange(value)` in your `success:` -> `var json = $.parseJSON(data); hashchange(json.VIDEOID);`. But looking in your function, I don't see where you are using the `value`, since you have `vid.src = location.hash.slice(1) + '.mp4';`

Comment: You identified a goal, but not a specific problem or question related to achieving that goal or any mention of what does or doesn't work in the code

Comment: Sorry, at the moment my php query is working and returning the video ID. The part i'm struggling with is how to pass the $vidarray to my AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can pass data to ajax.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: <?php echo $vidarray["id"]; ?>,
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(result) {
    //result downloaded so we call parseJSON function
    //and pass downloaded result
    var json = $.parseJSON(result);
    //Not sure what to do after this
 }
```

});